# Browser Sync + Gulp + Jade, Why separate the Jade watch task?

Tags: javascript, gulp, pug, browser-sync

I was looking at this [browser sync recipe](https://github.com/BrowserSync/recipes/blob/master/recipes/gulp.jade/gulpfile.js) which is a gulpfile configuration that works with jade, sass and browser sync, I don't care about sass so to simplify I modified the code a little:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var jade        = require('gulp-jade');
var reload      = browserSync.reload;

/**
 * Compile jade files into HTML
 */
gulp.task('templates', function() {
    return gulp.src('./app/*.jade')
        .pipe(jade())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});

/**
 * Important!!
 * Separate task for the reaction to `.jade` files
 */
gulp.task('jade-watch', ['templates'], reload);


/**
 * Serve and watch the jade files for changes
 */
gulp.task('default', ['templates'], function () {
    browserSync({server: './dist'});
    gulp.watch('./app/*.jade', ['jade-watch']);
});
```

What I don't understand is this comment:

```
/**
 * Important!!
 * Separate task for the reaction to `.jade` files
 */
```

Why is this important? Why not just do this?

```
/**
 * Compile jade files into HTML
 */
gulp.task('templates', function() {
    return gulp.src('./app/*.jade')
        .pipe(jade())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

/**
 * Serve and watch the jade files for changes
 */
gulp.task('default', ['templates'], function () {
    browserSync({server: './dist'});
    gulp.watch('./app/*.jade', ['templates']);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have figured this out by now; but in case anyone else comes along wondering the same thing (as I did): by setting the 'templates' task as a dependency of 'jade-watch' you ensure it has completed before triggering reload.